# How can I acces the Andorid Activity in another object?

Tags: java, android

I have the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements View.OnClickListener, FragmentA.SomeListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        String helloWorld = getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world);

        new YqlVplanParser(){ // A AsyncTask
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String jsonString) {
                JsonArray result = JsonArray.readFrom(jsonString);
                result.toString();

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(/*HERE I NEED THE ACTIVITY*/, "Nachricht", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();

            }
        }.execute("query");
    }   
}
```

So normaly I would write `this` where `/*HERE I NEED THE ACTIVITY*/` stands, but how can I access the activity now? this would refer to my AsyncTask.

Answer (score 2):

Use `MainActivity.this` to indicate that you want the `this` from the outer class. You are creating an anonymous inner class (subclass of `YqlVplanParser`), so `this` is the instance of the inner class.

Answer (score 2):

you can access MainActivity`s context this way:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Nachricht", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
 toast.show();
```